# Python clear each list in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists, like this:

```
results = {'Thing' : [], 'SecondThing': []}
```

After some processing, I need to clear each list in the dictionary without removing the mapping, but I'm not sure how to iterate it, as Python tells me that it's a str

```
for key in results:
    print(type(key))
```

But I don't want the key, I want the value, so I tried:

```
for key,value in results:
```

But I'm told that there are `too many values to unpack`, so I'm obviously doing something silly.

Comment: `for key,value in results.items():`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply assign the empty list to each dictionary value:

```
for key in results:
    results[key] = []
```

or if you don't want to have a different `list` object after clearing all lists, just call `list.clear()` on those:

```
for key in results:
    results[key].clear()
```

Comment: What are the advantages and disadvantages of  `clear()` over creating a new list object in view from speed and  memory?

Comment: It is not a matter of speed, it is a matter of object references: the lists can be referenced somewhere else, and clearing the list will have an effect everywhere, while reassigning the empty list will have an effect only on this dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use:

```
for val in results.values():
    do_whatever(val)
```

Similarly, `results.keys()` will give you the keys ('Thing' and 'SecondThing') and `.items()` will give you tuples of (key,value).

Answer (score -1):

Also if you want to iterate over key and value:

```
d = {'Hello':'Welt'}
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```